# understanding the count of a parameter while debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging

While i am debugging i wanted to see if my parameters are being passed in and counted and just wanted some clarification for the following method:

```
public void Create(VisitEntry visitEntry,IList<Guid>caseIds, IList<Guid>partyIds )  
{..code..}
```

when i hover over visitEntry i see most of the populated fields/items that i have. And hovering over caseIds it says: Count=2 and hovering over partyId: System.Guid[1].

What does it really mean: System.Guid[1] - and why not show as caseIds whether Count = 1 or Count = 2?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because in the first case the concrete type is `List<Guid>` for `caseIds` and `Guid[]` for `partyIds`:

For example run the following code and you will see the difference:

```
List<Guid> caseIds = new List<Guid> { Guid.NewGuid() };
Guid[] partyIds = new Guid[] { Guid.NewGuid() };
```